# Trouble in Deploying Node.js to Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I am new to mongodb and nodejs. I am using the boilerplate provided by https://anmolkoul.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/interactive-data-visualization-using-d3-js-dc-js-nodejs-and-mongodb/.

I want to deploy this app online through heroku open but it returns "Application Error: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.".

I typed heroku logs in my terminal and the result is shown below. Can someone kindly enlighten me the problem? I can run the app locally.

Heroku Logs:

[image: Heroku Logs]

Comment: Can you put logs as text if possible?

Comment: Where are the logs?